# is it posible to invert a group by statement?

Tags: mysql

A quick MySQL question.
Ff I have a table with columns a|b|c|d|e|f|num as an example
is there anyway I could do something like SELECT a, b, ..,f, sum(num) GROUP BY a, b, .., f
without adding that group by list in the back. The reason I want to do this is that I will have an array of fields that I dont want to include in the group by, and when it is empty I want to group by all fields.

In essence If I have an array containing (a, c, e)
I want to generate a query like this SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, sum(num) as num group by b, d, f
but by writing something like SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, sum(num) group by inverse a, c, e, sum

Does some syntax like this exist?

Thanks

Comment: No it doesn't exist, and it doesn't make sense. Values you'd get in non-aggregated columns not mentioned in group by clause would be essentialy random and thus useless.

Comment: that is why I a trying to see if it is possible to mention all values in the group by clause and specify only the exclusions. I can handle the random numbers.

Comment: No such syntax in MySQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct SQL you can do for that.

However, you may want to attempt some dynamic SQL using information_schema.columns

```
mysql> desc information_schema.columns;
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_CATALOG            | varchar(512)        | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA             | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME               | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLUMN_NAME              | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| ORDINAL_POSITION         | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| COLUMN_DEFAULT           | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IS_NULLABLE              | varchar(3)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| DATA_TYPE                | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH   | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUMERIC_PRECISION        | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUMERIC_SCALE            | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHARACTER_SET_NAME       | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLLATION_NAME           | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_TYPE              | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_KEY               | varchar(3)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| EXTRA                    | varchar(27)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| PRIVILEGES               | varchar(80)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLUMN_COMMENT           | varchar(1024)       | NO   |     |         |       |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
19 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Let's suppose you have a table test.customers

```
mysql> desc test.customers;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| companyname | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address     | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone       | char(12)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Those columns exist in information_schema.columns. You can retrieve them with:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) column_list FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='test' AND table_name='customers';
```

It gives you this:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) column_list FROM information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE table_schema='test' AND table_name='customers';
+--------------------------------------------+
| column_list                                |
+--------------------------------------------+
| id,companyname,address,phone,email,contact |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Let's say you want to get everything not in (id,companyname,phone,email).

You could query it like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.column_name) column_list
FROM
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema='test'
    AND table_name='customers'
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'id' column_name
    UNION SELECT 'companyname'
    UNION SELECT 'phone'
    UNION SELECT 'email'
) exclusion
USING (column_name)
WHERE exclusion.column_name IS NULL;
```

Look what it gives you:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.column_name) column_list
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT column_name
    ->     FROM information_schema.columns
    ->     WHERE table_schema='test'
    ->     AND table_name='customers'
    -> ) A
    -> LEFT JOIN
    -> (
    ->   SELECT 'id' column_name
    ->   UNION SELECT 'companyname'
    ->   UNION SELECT 'phone'
    ->   UNION SELECT 'email'
    -> ) exclusion
    -> USING (column_name)
    -> WHERE exclusion.column_name IS NULL;
+-----------------+
| column_list     |
+-----------------+
| address,contact |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

OK, how do you build the query you are looking for?

Let's say

- your table is called mytable in the mydb database
- it has the columns a,b,c,d,e,f,num
- you want to perform an inverse on a,c,e,num

You would have to build the query dynamically. Here it goes:

Step 01) Create exclusion list for a,c,e,num

```
SELECT 'a' column_name
UNION SELECT 'c'
UNION SELECT 'e'
UNION SELECT 'num';
```

Step 02) Create the query to use the exclusion list against mydb.mytable

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.column_name) column_list
FROM
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema='mydb'
    AND table_name='mytable'
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'a' column_name
    UNION SELECT 'c'
    UNION SELECT 'e'
    UNION SELECT 'num'
) exclusion
USING (column_name)
WHERE exclusion.column_name IS NULL;
```

Step 03) Capture the output into a variable (gbc is group by columns)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.column_name)
INTO @gbc
FROM
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema='mydb'
    AND table_name='mytable'
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'a' column_name
    UNION SELECT 'c'
    UNION SELECT 'e'
    UNION SELECT 'num'
) exclusion
USING (column_name)
WHERE exclusion.column_name IS NULL;
```

Step 04) Create your full query

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,sum(num) from mydb.mytable group by ',@gbc);
```

Step 05) Execute the Dynamic SQL

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

If you want all columns to group by a,b,c,d,e,f then just use this as the exclusion list

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.column_name)
INTO @gbc
FROM
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema='mydb'
    AND table_name='mytable'
) A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'a' column_name
) exclusion
USING (column_name)
WHERE exclusion.column_name IS NULL;
```